# Javascript/Coffeescript Sorting an array of objects on multiple keys when the values are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, coffeescript

I'm trying to sort an array of object by key but that when the value of the key of object a is the same as that of object b, the next key will be checked until they finally differ.

I've tried using the following code:

```
rows.sort (a, b) ->
   for key, value of a
      if a[key] < b[key]
        return -1
      else if a[key] > b[key]
        return 1
      else
        continue
```

But this causes the array to look differently when the initial order is different. Any ideas on a way to achieve it?
Thanks!

EDIT An array before:

```
[ { date: "2013-02-03",
    cpc: 1.46,
    cost: 1.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-05",
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 14.7,
    clicks: 8 },
  { date: "2013-02-06",
    cpc: 1.17,
    cost: 7.02,
    clicks: 6 },
  { date: "2013-02-09",
    cpc: 0.23,
    cost: 0.23,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-15",
    cpc: 1.4949999999999999,
    cost: 2.9899999999999998,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: "2013-02-17",
    cpc: 1.21,
    cost: 2.42,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: "2013-02-18",
    cpc: 1.92,
    cost: 9.6,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: "2013-02-02",
    cpc: 1.86,
    cost: 1.86,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-04",
    cpc: 2.35,
    cost: 2.35,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-11",
    cpc: 1.9625,
    cost: 7.85,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: "2013-02-16",
    cpc: 2.315,
    cost: 4.63,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: "2013-02-21",
    cpc: 1.8566666666666667,
    cost: 5.57,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: "2013-02-22",
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 7.35,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: "2013-02-25",
    cpc: 1.5066666666666668,
    cost: 4.5200000000000005,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: "2013-02-26",
    cpc: 2.6,
    cost: 2.6,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-27",
    cpc: 2.118,
    cost: 10.59,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: "2013-02-07",
    cpc: 0.2,
    cost: 0.2,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-08",
    cpc: 1.7850000000000001,
    cost: 7.140000000000001,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: "2013-02-10",
    cpc: 0.46,
    cost: 0.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-14",
    cpc: 1.955,
    cost: 3.91,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: "2013-02-19",
    cpc: 1.9233333333333331,
    cost: 17.31,
    clicks: 9 },
  { date: "2013-02-12",
    cpc: 2.39,
    cost: 7.17,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: "2013-02-13",
    cpc: 2.53,
    cost: 2.53,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-20",
    cpc: 1.87,
    cost: 1.87,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: "2013-02-23",
    cpc: 2.265,
    cost: 9.06,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: "2013-02-28",
    cpc: 2.2425,
    cost: 8.97,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: "2013-03-01",
    cpc: 1.83,
    cost: 3.66,
    clicks: 2 } ]
```

And the result after sorting (this is what I would be expecting from it):

```
[ { date: '2013-02-02',
    cpc: 1.86,
    cost: 1.86,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-03',
    cpc: 1.46,
    cost: 1.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-04',
    cpc: 2.35,
    cost: 2.35,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-05',
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 14.7,
    clicks: 8 },
  { date: '2013-02-06',
    cpc: 1.17,
    cost: 7.02,
    clicks: 6 },
  { date: '2013-02-07',
    cpc: 0.2,
    cost: 0.2,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-08',
    cpc: 1.7850000000000001,
    cost: 7.140000000000001,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-09',
    cpc: 0.23,
    cost: 0.23,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-10',
    cpc: 0.46,
    cost: 0.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-11',
    cpc: 1.9625,
    cost: 7.85,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-12',
    cpc: 2.39,
    cost: 7.17,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-13',
    cpc: 2.53,
    cost: 2.53,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-14',
    cpc: 1.955,
    cost: 3.91,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-15',
    cpc: 1.4949999999999999,
    cost: 2.9899999999999998,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-16',
    cpc: 2.315,
    cost: 4.63,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-17',
    cpc: 1.21,
    cost: 2.42,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-18',
    cpc: 1.92,
    cost: 9.6,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: '2013-02-19',
    cpc: 1.9233333333333331,
    cost: 17.31,
    clicks: 9 },
  { date: '2013-02-20',
    cpc: 1.87,
    cost: 1.87,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-21',
    cpc: 1.8566666666666667,
    cost: 5.57,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-22',
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 7.35,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-23',
    cpc: 2.265,
    cost: 9.06,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-25',
    cpc: 1.5066666666666668,
    cost: 4.5200000000000005,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-26',
    cpc: 2.6,
    cost: 2.6,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-27',
    cpc: 2.118,
    cost: 10.59,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: '2013-02-28',
    cpc: 2.2425,
    cost: 8.97,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-03-01',
    cpc: 1.83,
    cost: 3.66,
    clicks: 2 } ]
```

When you the order is hussled, initial array:

```
[ { date: '2013-02-02',
    cpc: 1.86,
    cost: 1.86,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-04',
    cpc: 2.35,
    cost: 2.35,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-05',
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 14.7,
    clicks: 8 },
  { date: '2013-02-06',
    cpc: 1.17,
    cost: 7.02,
    clicks: 6 },
  { date: '2013-02-11',
    cpc: 1.9625,
    cost: 7.85,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-12',
    cpc: 2.39,
    cost: 7.17,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-16',
    cpc: 2.315,
    cost: 4.63,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-18',
    cpc: 1.92,
    cost: 9.6,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: '2013-02-20',
    cpc: 1.87,
    cost: 1.87,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-21',
    cpc: 1.8566666666666667,
    cost: 5.57,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-28',
    cpc: 2.2425,
    cost: 8.97,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-03-01',
    cpc: 1.83,
    cost: 3.66,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-03',
    cpc: 1.46,
    cost: 1.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-07',
    cpc: 0.2,
    cost: 0.2,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-09',
    cpc: 0.23,
    cost: 0.23,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-10',
    cpc: 0.46,
    cost: 0.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-17',
    cpc: 1.21,
    cost: 2.42,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-19',
    cpc: 1.9233333333333331,
    cost: 17.31,
    clicks: 9 },
  { date: '2013-02-25',
    cpc: 1.5066666666666668,
    cost: 4.5200000000000005,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-08',
    cpc: 1.7850000000000001,
    cost: 7.140000000000001,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-13',
    cpc: 2.53,
    cost: 2.53,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-14',
    cpc: 1.955,
    cost: 3.91,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-15',
    cpc: 1.4949999999999999,
    cost: 2.9899999999999998,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-22',
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 7.35,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-23',
    cpc: 2.265,
    cost: 9.06,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-26',
    cpc: 2.6,
    cost: 2.6,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-27',
    cpc: 2.118,
    cost: 10.59,
    clicks: 5 }]
```

Result from sorting with hussled array:

```
[ { date: '2013-02-02',
    cpc: 1.86,
    cost: 1.86,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-03',
    cpc: 1.46,
    cost: 1.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-04',
    cpc: 2.35,
    cost: 2.35,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-05',
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 14.7,
    clicks: 8 },
  { date: '2013-02-06',
    cpc: 1.17,
    cost: 7.02,
    clicks: 6 },
  { date: '2013-02-07',
    cpc: 0.2,
    cost: 0.2,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-08',
    cpc: 1.7850000000000001,
    cost: 7.140000000000001,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-10',
    cpc: 0.46,
    cost: 0.46,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-11',
    cpc: 1.9625,
    cost: 7.85,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-12',
    cpc: 2.39,
    cost: 7.17,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-13',
    cpc: 2.53,
    cost: 2.53,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-14',
    cpc: 1.955,
    cost: 3.91,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-15',
    cpc: 1.4949999999999999,
    cost: 2.9899999999999998,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-16',
    cpc: 2.315,
    cost: 4.63,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-17',
    cpc: 1.21,
    cost: 2.42,
    clicks: 2 },
  { date: '2013-02-18',
    cpc: 1.92,
    cost: 9.6,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: '2013-02-19',
    cpc: 1.9233333333333331,
    cost: 17.31,
    clicks: 9 },
  { date: '2013-02-20',
    cpc: 1.87,
    cost: 1.87,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-21',
    cpc: 1.8566666666666667,
    cost: 5.57,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-22',
    cpc: 1.8375,
    cost: 7.35,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-23',
    cpc: 2.265,
    cost: 9.06,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-02-09',
    cpc: 0.23,
    cost: 0.23,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-25',
    cpc: 1.5066666666666668,
    cost: 4.5200000000000005,
    clicks: 3 },
  { date: '2013-02-26',
    cpc: 2.6,
    cost: 2.6,
    clicks: 1 },
  { date: '2013-02-27',
    cpc: 2.118,
    cost: 10.59,
    clicks: 5 },
  { date: '2013-02-28',
    cpc: 2.2425,
    cost: 8.97,
    clicks: 4 },
  { date: '2013-03-01',
    cpc: 1.83,
    cost: 3.66,
    clicks: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, added to clarify. I expect the first example of the sorted array to be what rolls out every time.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't really matter which one as long as it ALWAYS returns the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `continue`. And make sure to return `0` when the objects are a match:

```coffee
rows.sort (a, b) ->
  for key, value of a
    if a[key] < b[key]
      return -1
    else if a[key] > b[key]
      return 1

  return 0
```

The larger problem - object keys aren't sorted. There's no reason to expect, each time through the for loop, that the first key will be date, the second will be cpc, etc. You really want to have a predefined array of the keys, in order, and use that instead of just getting the key list from the objects

```coffee
keys = ["a","b","c"]

rows.sort (a, b) ->
  for key in keys
    if a[key] < b[key]
      return -1
    else if a[key] > b[key]
     return 1

  return 0
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/MYNBzP)

Comment: O wow. First of all, thanks for the quick response!
I was so focussed on the next key I didn't even think of this. So obvious. Thank you so much! Doing this though, I still get a different order out of it when the order of the initial array is different.

Comment: Then you'd need to post an example of an array that shows the problem (in the question, not as a comment, for best results).

Comment: Yes sorry, added! ;) (didn't add before because they are very long)

Comment: The larger problem - object keys aren't sorted. There's no reason to expect, each time through the `for` loop, that the first `key` will be `date`, the second will be `cpc`, etc. You really want to have a predefined array of the keys, in order, and use that instead of just getting the `key` list from the objects.

Comment: @muistooshort Good point. Moved it, with code, to the answer.

Comment: Good point, though I don't know in advance what keys I will have to deal with. In this case it would work, but if a user requests more than these keys or something completely different it won't work anymore.

Comment: Then use the keys the user requests. Point is, you *can't* count on the keys coming from the object to be in a useful order.

Comment: @PaulRoub Thanks, I guess I'll do that then. You can't really count on those being in the same order every time either, but the ones in the request are a lot more reliable in my case. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was about asking this question but found there was a similar question, turned out that the answer was something I was already doing but this had a FOR IN loop.
I tested it out and it wasn't giving me what I wanted
Then I decided to swap out the for in loop for a little more code when the values are the same.
Here are the results

[image: Looping through the given keys and comparing all]

[image: The loop outcome]

[image: Comparing a different key value pair when the initial values compared are the same]

[image: The outcome]